# Bounding an unknown IVP solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Given the Following IVP:
$$y'=f(x,y)=\frac 1 {2+{\cos(xy)}}$$
$$y(0)=\frac 1 2$$
I need to show that the IVP has a single solution $u(x)$ that is defined in $(-\infty,\infty)$, increasing, and that $u(x)<x$ for all $x>1$

I was able to show, using the fact that $f_y(x,y)=\frac {x \sin(xy)} {{2+\cos(xy)}^2}$ is bounded in $[a,b]\times(-\infty,\infty)$ for all $a$,$b$, that there exist a single solution, and to show that it's derivative is positive, so that it is increasing, but I couldn't get the inequality right.

I Tried using the Mean Value Theorem but the bound that I got wasn't tight enough ($u(x)<x+\frac 1 2$). I also tried to bound integral up to a general point $x>1$ but this didn't work either.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y(x)$ be the unique solution to the IVP, which is unique because as the OP said, $f(x,y)$ is locally Lipschitz in $y$ and continuous in $x$. Global existence follows because $y'(x)$ is bounded from above and below: it is impossible for the solution to blow up in finite time.

It suffices to show $y(1) \leq 1.$ By the fundamental theorem of calculus,
$$y(1) - y(0) = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{2 + \cos(x\cdot y(x))}dx.$$
You deduced from the properties of cosine that
$$\frac{1}{3} \leq y'(x) \leq 1$$
so in turn
$$\frac{1}{3}x + \frac{1}{2} \leq y(x) \leq x+ \frac{1}{2} .$$
This implies for $x\in [0,1]$, $$0 < y(x) < \frac{3}{2} \leq \frac{\pi}{2}.$$
However, this is great news, because it implies $\cos(x\cdot y(x)) \geq 0$ for $x \in [0,1].$

From this point, you can conclude $$y(1) - y(0) \leq \frac{1}{2}$$
and therefore $y(1) \leq 1.$ With the bound $y'(x) \leq 1$ we can conclude the desired bound $y(x) \leq x.$

Comment: Nice answer. Do you think that is could be possible to prove that $y\sim \frac x 2+\epsilon$ (which is true) ?

Comment: Intuitively it should be true that $y \sim x/2$ because $\cos(x\cdot y(x))$ oscillates a lot as $x \to \infty$. A numerical check seems to indicate that it's more like $y \sim .577x$. You can't prove $y \sim x/2$ with L'Hopital's rule unfortunately because the limit of $y'(x)$ does not exist, but maybe you could do something with partitioning the domain of cosine, or some trick that lets us get rid of the oscillation. (Maybe something you'd see in Fourier analysis?)